# Android: How to automatically sync data between container <--> sql database?

Tags: android, database, synchronization

I would like to add the offline capability to my app and I would like to know which solution prefers for 2-way sync between the container and local SQL database?

Scenario:

**Online app:**

- Data are fetched from REST
- Data are parsed and saved to Container    (all app components are
  reading data from the Container)
- Data are synced between Container and Database

**Offline app:**

- Container is keeping filled from Database (sync)
- The app is taking the data from the synced container. When data are changed in the container, data are synced in Database.
- Changed data are synced against the REST when the app comes online.
- List item

Data stored in the database should be encrypted by default.

Which libraries for this u are using please and what is you recommendations, please?

Comment: Did you have a look at the new Room Persistence Library ?https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Comment: take a look on realm https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/